# Cannot find TestView in scope

Tags: macos, swiftui, ios14

I am seeing the following error in iOS14, I am not sure if it is a bug or a user error :-)
I appreciate it is still in beta, so I will post this in the developer forums as well.

I am seeing the following error come up when I make a macOS app in SwiftUI - when I create the same as an iOS app, the error does not appear.

Do I need to do something special for macOS apps when it comes to importing SwiftUI modules?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the file target membership that has `TestView` defined

Comment: Try to move TestView in same .swift file where that TabView is used.

Comment: This bug happens to me when I move files around. Close your Xcode project and reopen it again for the error to disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Asperi and staticVoidMan - your comments where both useful and I learned something.

Comment: I have this problem after moving files postions.

Answer (score 11):

Had this issue today because I renamed the file that contained the class. The solution was to delete the file and recreate it.

Answer (score 10):

Don't forget to add it to your **Target Membership**

[image]

Comment: That's was the case for me.

Answer (score 3):

- Clean the project
- Close and relaunch the Xcode

This will solve the problem.

Comment: It didn't - I needed to add it to the target membership, which was said in the comments

Comment: yes that need to be done. But in my case I was getting same error even it is added to target member

Answer (score 2):

In my case the reason was that the protocol I was inheriting in the class, needed to be made public.

Answer (score 0):

When you rename a swift View from Project navigator or refactor the name within a struct, check that the struct and preview name were updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you've selected "Create folder references" when adding a new file to the project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had this today, but found that I renamed my file's name but I forgot to rename the corresponding struct within it. That fixed my issue.